# Error switching view objective-c

Tags: uiviewcontroller, crash, xib

When I want to switch from viewcontroller to Register.xib I get an error and end up in main.m. It worked when I didn't have any variables in my Register.h but as soon as I add a variable it doesn't work.

```
-(IBAction)Register:(UIButton *)sender
{
    //[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Register" owner:self options:nil];
    if(!reg)
    {
        reg = [[Register alloc]initWithNibName:@"Register" bundle:nil];
    }

    UIBarButtonItem *backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backBarButtonItem;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:reg animated:YES];

}
```

When I press the register-button I end up here:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show us the `initWithNibName` of your Register class.

Comment: - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}